# Troubles Unwinding a MongoDB collection: Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of Keys within mongoDB that have the form:

```
{"Number": [
    "4700100004"
],
"Random": [
    "unknown"
],
"List_Of_Vals": [
    "3",
    "2",
    "1",
]}
```

And these jsons could have any number of keys with lists.

I would like to Unwind the list and commit it to say another collection. but I get a duplicate key error when I write this:

```
import json
import glob
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.code import Code
from bson.son import SON


pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": "$_id"},{"$unwind": "$List_Of_Vals"},{"$out": "UnWound"}
]

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.database
collection = db.collection

collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

which I am not sure how to get around. Ultimately I think I am confused about how to go through my entire collection and unwind everything within it and commit it to another collection.

Comment: Well `{ "$unwind": "$_id" }` is more likely to error since it would not be an array, nor could be an array in the rules for primary keys for stored objects. When you process `$unwind` on an array it is going to "copy" the whole document outside of the array being processed, and leave behind a document per array member. Naturally when using `$out` you cannot keep the current document `_id` since it will be duplicated per element. You can of course simply remove the `_id` in a `$project` stage. But I would question exactly what you need to write to another collection, as well as the purpose.

Comment: hmm I will give that a shot... The purpose of this is to create a document for every item in the list. Ultimately I would like to transition into RDBMS so this is so this is part of my guess check learn as i go process

Comment: Even if you want to transition it does not mean it is good to model this way for MongoDB. MongoDB *"does not do joins"*, and therefore anything in seperate collections **needs** aditional query operations in order to retrieve the "related" data. Usually content is embedded like this for a reason, or at least it should have been done for a reason. If you write to other collections then you need to consider how you are going to reference one thing to the other, and the performance considerations therin. Relational schemas are best left to relational databases.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I see what your saying. Unfortunately I am obligated to use pentaho as the intermediary step between mongo and postgres or mysql. and I know nothing about it I would rather query a document do the cleaning and populate RDB table all in python. Pentaho cant handle the size of the document created when I unwind the data to stick it into an an RDB table. most likely because im using the program wrong